# Why does Arya have Beric Dondarrion in her list?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As far as I remember Beric got his duty from Ned Stark. What did Beric do to be in Arya's kill list?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Because he sold Gendry out to Melisandre.**

Note that he's not on her kill list in the books, only in the TV show.

The full list from the show is as follows (list more or less copied from [here](http://www.tvguide.com/news/game-of-thrones-arya-kill-list/), updated with status **including spoilers from S8**):

> - **The Hound**
>   *Why:* For killing Mycah, the butcher's boy.
>   *Status:* **Dead.** Cleganebowl.
> - **Meryn Trant**
>   *Why:* For (presumably) killing Syrio Forel.
>   *Status:* **Dead.** Arya slit his throat in a Braavosi brothel where Meryn was abusing underage girls.
> - **Cersei Lannister**
>   *Why:* For her role in Ned Stark's death.
>   *Status:* **Dead**.
> - **Joffrey**
>   *Why:* For ordering Ned Stark's execution.
>   *Status:* **Dead.** Joffrey was poisoned by Olenna Tyrell and Petyr Baelish at his wedding to Margaery. Unfortunately, Arya's sister Sansa was suspected of the murder and had to go on the run.
> - **Ilyn Payne**
>   *Why:* For executing Ned Stark.
>   *Status:* **Alive** - as far as we know.
> - **Polliver**
>   *Why:* For killing Lommy, stealing Needle and the torture at Harrenhal.
>   *Status:* **Dead.** Arya killed him after a chance encounter at an inn.
> - **The Mountain**
>   *Why:* For the torture at Harrenhal
>   *Status:* **Dead.** Cleganebowl.
> - **Rorge**
>   *Why:* For the torture at Harrenhal and threatening to rape her.
>   *Status:* **Dead.** Arya killed him after Rorge and Biter attacked her and the Hound.
> - **Walder Frey**
>   *Why:* For orchestrating the Red Wedding
>   *Status:* **Dead.** As of the Season 6 finale Arya used her assassin skills (including face-changing!) to infiltrate Riverrun and kill him
> - **Tywin Lannister**
>   *Why:* For orchestrating the Red Wedding.
>   *Status:* **Dead.** Tyrion killed his father with a crossbow while Tywin was using the toilet.
> - **Melisandre**
>   *Why:* For kidnapping Gendry.
>   *Status:* **Dead.**
> - **Beric Dondarrion**
>   *Why:* For selling Gendry to Melisandre.
>   *Status:* **Dead.**
> - **Thoros of Myr**
>   *Why:* For selling Gendry to Melisandre.
>   *Status:* **Dead.** Mauled by undead polar bear.  Succumbs to wounds and cold.

Comment: Her list is too confusing to me and don't make much sense.

Comment: Syrio Forel is not dead ( not confirmed at least)

Comment: @AnkitSharma Trant *meant* to kill him, and *almost certainly* did kill him, which is enough to get on Arya's kill list.

Comment: I think Arya later on removed the Hound from the list. Or maybe that was only in the books, not sure about that. And I think she didn't remove him because she thinks he's dead but because she actually forgave him. See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/when-did-arya-take-the-hound-out-of-her-prayer

Comment: @AnkitSharma It's not confirmed, but the most reasonable assumption is to believe he is dead: one killer with armor and a steel sword enters the room where Syrio is unarmored and only has a wooden sword. The killer leaves the room alone. What additional evidence do we need? :)

Comment: @AndresF. Evidence that Syrio wasn't from a certain group of water dancing fellows also known to hail from Bravos... Were he, the opportunities would be as endless as a hall full of faces.

Comment: @Axelord It'd be pretty disappointing if that were the case. Most people from Braavos aren't Faceless Men. Plus it doesn't work that way: the onus is on the people making the extraordinary claim (i.e. that Syrio was a Faceless Man and survived); you don't need additional evidence for the most reasonable interpretation! *Unless* we're shown additional info -- and at this point in the story, it'd be irrelevant in my opinion -- Syrio is dead and buried.

Comment: “Mauled by undead polar bear.” I might have that for my gravestone.

Comment: @AndresF. Whose version of reasonable? The real rule with TV deaths is thusly listed: if it doesn't happen on-screen, [it didn't happen until proven otherwise.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfPerception) XD

Comment: @Axelord Mine, obviously. If this was an original HBO series, I'd be inclined to agree with you. But in the books Syrio's death seems final, and books don't follow that trope as closely as TV shows :)